# Discord.py bot ignoring channel.message.id

Tags: python, if-statement, discord.py, bots

I have a bot that every 1 to 12 hours sends a random message into a specific channel (the channel that the command !random is used in). A certain handful of these message are yes/no questions, and I want to make it that the bot will respond if somebody says yes/no.

The code works, the issue is I want the bot to respond ONLY if the person answered yes/no in the same channel the bot sent the original message, not just any channel (because this may disrupt other actual conversations).

The issue is, the bot seems to always think the id entered for message.channel.id is wrong. I've triple checked and it is indeed the correct channel where I used the command and the bot is sending the messages there, it is also where I'm replying to the bot as I would want for the "if" condition to work. Here's the code:

```
@bot.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
  global newvalue
    if newvalue == True:
        if 'no' in message.content and message.channel.id == "<#988993107368476692>":
            await message.channel.send("first response")
            newvalue = False
            return
        if 'yes' in message.content and message.channel.id == "<#988993107368476692>":
            await message.channel.send("second response")
            newvalue = False
            return
        else:
          print("nothing to say!")
          return
   await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Like I said, the code before I added message.channel.id worked fine, except that if I answered the bot in a different channel, it would answer me back in that new channel instead of not reading the message at all (which is what I want, hence this code).

But, even though I'm keeping it to the correct channel, my terminal keeps printing "nothing to say!", meaning it's passing over those two if statements now.

I've tried making it 2 separate if statements (if 'no': if in channel: etc) but that doesn't work either.

tldr how do I make a bot respond only if a user's message is sent to a specific channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, turns out I'm stupid lol. I had to do what @anoor1234 suggested but make it a separate if function

```
if newvalue == True:
        if 'no' in message.content:
          if message.channel.id == 988993107368476692:
            await message.channel.send("first response")
            newvalue = False
            return
        if 'yes' in message.content:
           if message.channel.id == 988993107368476692:
            await message.channel.send("second response")
            newvalue = False
            return
```

This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the ID your using is not formatted correctly. `message.channel.id` returns an integer, like `988993107368476692`, not a string like `"<#988993107368476692>"`. Replace all instances of `<#988993107368476692>` with `988993107368476692`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've tried 988993107368476692 both with and without the accompanying <#> and both versions with and without surrounding it in quotations. None of them worked :( I get the same result